# How to create json format java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I would like to create JSON format and I have some problem about this

I have no idea to create `Jsonarray` and `JsonObject` in `JsonObject`

```
{
   "users": [7, 16, 35],
   "group_id": "sdkfjsdkljflds"
}
```

I try

```
JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

try {
    jsonParams.put("group_id", "dlfsdds");
    jsonParams.put("users", list);

} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and  my **log** is show

```
{
   "users":"[7, 16, 35]",
   "group_id":"dlfsdds"
}
```

ps. list is from

```
for (int k=0;k<allMember.size();k++){
    list.add(allMember.get(k));
}
```

what is my mistake? and How to fix it?

thank for your help:D

Comment: You probably need to create a `JSONArray` from the `list`, and then add that. Otherwise the list will be converted to a string when it is added to the `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the list to `JSONArray` first:

```
try {
    jsonParams.put("group_id", "dlfsdds");

    JSONArray listJson = new JSONArray();

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        listJson.put(list.get(i));
    }


    jsonParams.put("users", listJson);

} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Most libraries also allow you to avoid the for-loop and simply do:

```
JSONArray listJson = new JSONArray(list);
```

Comment: umm , sorry but it's not correct ,I want to set `"users": [7, 16, 35]` not `"users":["7", "16", "35"]`

Comment: @ARR.s It means that `list` is a `List<String>`. Change it to `List<Integer>`.